# Deserialize XML in a WP8 Application

Tags: c#, xml, windows, windows-phone-7, deserialization

I'm trying to develop a Windows phone 8 app (I'm new in wp8 dev).

I have an XML file that look like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<root>
   <quotes>
      <quote>
         <author></author>
         <text></text>
         <text></text>
         <text></text>
      </quote>
   </quotes>
</root>
```

---

This is my Quotes class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Quotes
{
   [XmlArray("quotes")]
   [XmlArrayItem("quote")]
   public ObservableCollection<Quote> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

---

This is the quote class:

```
public class Quote
{
   [XmlElement("author")]
   public string author { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("text")]
   public string text { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then I use this code to deserialize it:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Quotes));
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
Quotes quotes = (Quotes) serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
quotesList.ItemsSource = quotes.Collection;
```

---

```
// selected Quote
        Quote quote;

        public QuotePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // get selected quote from App Class
            var app = App.Current as App;
            quote = app.selectedQuote;

            // show quote details in page
            author.Text = quote.author;
            text.Text = quote.text;

        }
```

This work fine in every feed having this structure with one `<text>` section. But I have feed with a lot of `<text>`

If I use C# code above, only first `<text>` section is parsed, others are ignored. I need to create separate List or ObservableCollection for each `<text>` section in single XML feed.

Comment: "This work fine in every feed having this structure with one section" - do you mean you have more than one quotes section ?

Comment: Show `Quote` class code.

Comment: It will be easier if you create a class with the structure you like and make a serialization. So that string will be what your xml need to be.

Comment: Hassan i have a lot of quotes section... this code is working only if i have one text tag.. thanks

Comment: @user1931853 You only have one property (getter setter) that takes you text tag.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I added the Quote class code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Quote` class to contain `List<string> text` instead of `string text`:

```
public class Quote
{
    [XmlElement("author")]
    public string author { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("text")]
    public List<string> text { get; set; }
}
```

***Update***

Because of existing functionality within your app and current `Quote` class members I would leave serialization and use LINQ to XML to load data from XML into `Quotes` class instance:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
Quotes quotes = new Quotes() {
    Collection = document.Root
                         .Element("quotes")
                         .Elements("quote")
                         .Select(q => new {
                             xml = q,
                             Author = (string) q.Element("author")
                         })
                         .SelectMany(q => q.xml.Elements("text")
                                           .Select(t => new Quote() {
                                                author = q.Author,
                                                text = (string)t
                                            }))
                         .ToList()
};
```

I've tested it with following `Quotes` and `Quote` class declarations:

```
public class Quotes
{
    public List<Quote> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public string author { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Attributes are no longer necessary because this approach does not use XmlSerialization.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's says cannot implicitly convert the 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'  so i suppose that i have to change the implementation in the page where i will show the the text but i don't know how to do this can you please help?: 
        Quote quote;

        public QuotePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var app = App.Current as App;
            quote = app.selectedQuote;

            // show quote details in page
            author.Text = quote.author;
            text.Text = quote.text;
            
        }

Comment: You probably has a reference to that property already set somewhere in your code. Could you update your question and write what objects (and it's content as well) would you like to achieve from that xml? Is it one `Quote` class object with author and list of texts, or maybe `List<Quote>` each with an author and one text from xml?

Comment: I have two pages in the first one i have all the authors and when i choose an author it shows all the texts of this author

Comment: I did what you said but still doesn't work...thank you for your help