# How to take an xml response received from a web service and make it a datasource

Tags: windows-phone

I'm making a windows 8.1 phone app and I have a listbox that I'm trying to populate with data. My problem is that I am using a web service and I finally figured out how to get the data but it is in an xml format and I don't know how to make that into the itemssource for the listbox. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but this is my first time doing this and I can't seem to find any information online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very simple example which requests an `XML` document from a URI over HTTPS.

It downloads the XML asynchronously as a string and then uses `XDocument.Parse()` to load it.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://domain/path/file.xml"));
}

private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

        this.textBox1.Text = xdoc.FirstNode.ToString();
    }
}
```

Have a look over [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7ac29a93-8280-4920-bd4f-9a7135ef4e31/reading-xml-from-web-service-c?forum=wpdevelop) thread.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the data coming back is always the same type you can always use XmlSerializer to deserialize the data the data to a class you can bind to.  If you copy a sample of the data coming back to the clip board you can use paste xml as classes to paste the class you can deserialize into

[Deserialize XML in a WP8 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480625/deserialize-xml-in-a-wp8-application)